# Who's Charlotte?

Tags: charlotte

Where does the title "Charlotte" come from? I don't remember a character or concept with that name. I don't remember the word even being spoken during the series itself. Do we know where it comes from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This contains a little bit of a spoiler, so I'll give a little warning....

> Charlotte is the name of the comet that passes over the earth every 75 years and gives everyone their super powers.
>
>  They mention this in Episode 11:
>  
>  [image]
>
>  [image]